# How do I read Dart Uint8list and convert them to Byte Array in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, dart

I want to read Uint8list value which is stored in a MySQL database and I want to convert them to byte array in C# so that I can convert the byte array to an image later.

On Dart I insert the Uint8list value to db using this way (Read byte of .png file):

```
  Uint8List _getFileValues = File(_FilePathVal).readAsBytesSync();
  bodyBytes = base64.encode(_getFileValues);

  var _Res = await conn.execute(
        "INSERT INTO " + tableName +  " (CUST_FILE) VALUES (:byteval)",
        {
          "byteval": bodyBytes
        },
      );
```

This is how I read the Uint8list value in C#:

```
 MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();

 da.Fill(ds);
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
 pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(ms);
```

But I got an error saying `Parameter is not valid` while trying to read the Uint8list value in C# on the line `pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(ms);`.

Is there any way I can make it possible to read the Uint8list value and convert them to C# byte array or do I need certain library for it?.

Comment: The Dart code doesn't write the raw byte data; it writes *base64-encoded* data.  If you need that encoding step, then you must correspondingly *decode* the data when you read it.

Comment: Thank you sir I kinda lost at first now I get it! I thought it's not possible to decode an encoded data from different PL.